# Left Join Subquery Exclude GROUP BY with null result

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a query with a `GROUP_CONCAT` added as a new column in my current query, first here are my tables:

```
Users table
+----+----------+--------------+
| id | username | date_created |
+----+----------+--------------+
|  1 | user1    | 2000-03-16   |
|  2 | user2    | 2001-05-14   |
|  3 | user3    | 2002-01-13   |
|  4 | user4    | 2003-03-14   |
+----+----------+--------------+

Shifts table
+----+------------+--------------+
| id | shift_name | date_created |
+----+------------+--------------+
|  1 | shift1     | 2002-05-10   |
|  2 | shift2     | 2002-07-11   |
|  3 | shift3     | 2002-09-23   |
+----+------------+--------------+

Accounts table
+----+--------------+--------------+
| id | account_name | date_created |
+----+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | account1     | 2001-05-01   |
|  2 | account2     | 2001-05-02   |
|  3 | account3     | 2001-05-03   |
+----+--------------+--------------+

Shift Mapping table
+----+---------+----------+------------+
| id | user_id | shift_id | account_id |
+----+---------+----------+------------+
|  1 |       1 |        1 |          1 |
|  2 |       1 |        2 |          2 |
|  3 |       3 |        1 |          1 |
+----+---------+----------+------------+
```

basically, I want a query that gets all the user (to display in a table) with a custom column that shows all shift that is attach to that user(if there is no shift attach to that obviously has a null result)

Here is the query I've done so far:

```
SELECT users.id AS user_id, users.username, users.date_created,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (t.shift_name)) AS shifts
FROM (`users`)
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT s.shift_name, sm.user_id FROM shift_map sm
    LEFT JOIN shifts s ON sm.shift_id = s.id) t 
ON users.id = t.user_id
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY `users`.`date_created` DESC;
```

Now there is no problem getting the users with a shift attach to it, my problem is that the users with no shifts attach to only returns 1 result which is caused by the `GROUP BY user_id` how can I exclude the users with no shift in the GROUP BY or how can I return all the users with attached shifts and with no attach shifts? Thanks.

**Update**

Here is the example result I want to see:

```
+---------+----------+--------------+----------------+
| user_id | username | date_created |     shifts     |
+---------+----------+--------------+----------------+
|       1 | user1    | 2000-03-16   | shift1,shift2  |
|       2 | user2    | 2001-05-14   | (NULL)         |
|       3 | user3    | 2002-01-13   | shift1         |
|       4 | user4    | 2003-03-14   | (NULL)         |
+---------+----------+--------------+----------------+
```

My problem in my query is that it only shows only 1 user with null shifts.

Comment: can you specify the exact output you are looking for?

Comment: hi @Sanj Updated my question for the example result.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT users.id AS user_id, users.username, users.date_created,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (t.shift_name)) AS shifts
FROM (`users`)
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT s.shift_name, sm.user_id FROM mapping sm
    LEFT JOIN shifts s ON sm.shift_id = s.id) t 
ON users.id = t.user_id
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY user_id

+---------+----------+--------------+---------------+
| user_id | username | date_created | shifts        |
+---------+----------+--------------+---------------+
|       1 | user1    | 2000-03-16   | shift1,shift2 |
|       2 | user2    | 2001-03-16   | NULL          |
|       3 | user3    | 2002-03-16   | shift1        |
|       4 | user4    | 2003-03-16   | NULL          |
+---------+----------+--------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

My Bad, I can just use the simple `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT users.id AS user_id, users.username, users.date_created,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (shift.shift_name)) AS shifts
FROM (`users`)
LEFT JOIN shifts_map ON users.id = shifts_map.user_id
LEFT JOIN shifts ON shifts_map.shift_id = shift.id
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY `users`.`date_created` DESC;
```

I am just complicating the query, Forgot that the simple `LEFT JOIN` can do the trick. Thanks.